# Why can't I access injected service from scaffolding template for controller?

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I have a controller which looks like this:

```
class CategoryController {

    static scaffold = true

    def messageSource

    def categoryService
    ...
}
```

I want to modify Controller template to use service when needed:

```
class ${className}Controller {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

    def list() {
        def domainObjectsProperty = ... //long complex line
        render view: "/${domainClass.propertyName}/list", model: [(domainObjectsProperty): ${domainClass.propertyName}Service.list()]
    }

    ...
}
```

Expression `${domainClass.propertyName}Service` is evaluated to `categoryService`, but I get message:

> No such property: categoryService for class:
>   mypackage.CategoryController

At the same time, when I call not scaffolded methods of CategoryController, which use CategoryService, everything is fine.

What causes this behavior and how to work around the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I've run into similar issues like this, going both directions. Using methods from the scaffolding in non-scaffolded methods, and also vice-verse seems to not work as one would expect it to intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the service injection

```
class ${className}Controller {

   def ${domainClass.propertyName}Service

   ... 
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing what the OP is asking for. He wants to use a property in the actual controller from inside scaffolded methods.